# Is there a way to set Firefox default bookmarks on new profiles?

Tags: firefox, debian, bookmarks

I distro hop often so I copy my `user.js` and `search.json.mozlz4` files to `/home/name/.mozilla/firefox/f00.profileName/user.js` etc. whenever I create a new Firefox profile and it applies my settings (don't know if there is a faster way)

I know I can Restore / Backup bookmarks via a *.json file but that is too many clicks :)

So I wonder if I can somehow add my default bookmarks to user.js or another file and copy them to profile folder? Like how the bookmarks toolbar has "Import bookmarks ..." and "Getting Started" by default, I would also prefer to remove them if possible.

Thanks for any help!

**P.S.:** If it makes any difference, I mainly use Firefox ESR that comes with Debian 12. But I would appreciate any solution that works in any other distro or Windows.

Comment: I also remember copying `places.sqlite` file but it caused some problems that I don't remember. If you are certain it's a valid solution, please verify and post it as well, I will accept.

Comment: `places.sqlite` is definitely where the bookmarks are stored, but all the official documentation I can find studiously avoids copying the file. Instead they suggest using the proper export to JSON tool that is built in. An alternative might be to use Mozilla Firefox Sync to save your bookmarks to a Firefox online account and download them to new distros that way. https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/features/sync/

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, and looks like you are right.. If you post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Maybe you can use Firefox policies, and particularly the `Bookmarks` policy for this: https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/#bookmarks

Comment: @raj this does looks useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative might be to use Mozilla Firefox Sync to save your bookmarks to a Firefox online account and download them to new distros that way. https://mozilla.org/firefox/features/sync

So if you sign into an account n Firefox on one distro to upload your bookmarks then when you go to a new distro and sign in there it should be able to download your bookmarks.

---

Regarding being able to just copy a file and have done with it seems that `places.sqlite` is definitely where the bookmarks are stored, I've simply copied it in the past myself but can't remember if there were any caveats. All the official documentation I can find studiously avoids copying the file so there seems to be some reason why you wouldn't want to do it.

Instead they suggest using the proper export to JSON tool that is built in, hence why I suggest bypassing that by using an online account that you can synchronise your bookmarks through.

Answer (score 1):

I use firefox policies (/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json) to add a default set of bookmarks to all new profiles, with the "ManagedBookmarks" option.  n.b. this are not user editable.

Also, similar to Mozilla Firefox Sync, I use the Floccus add-on with Nextcloud. Floccus is also available for Chrome based browsers, so I can sync between different browsers too!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).